# what the difference between margin and padding in Container widget using Flutter framework?

Tags: flutter, padding, margin

```
class app1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Hello ',
        home: Material(
          child: Container (
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter ,
            //padding: EdgeInsets.all (30 ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget> [
                Text ( 'Hello There ' , style: TextStyle (fontSize: 30 ) ),
                ],
              ),
          ),
          ),



          )
    );

  }
}
```

**I have a text widget when i apply the margin and after that apply the padding same result ? so what's the different ?** [image]

Comment: margin is usually a measurement from the edges of the work area (screen). While padding is typically the spacing between different elements within that area. Try adding a second element then adjusting the padding and you will see the difference.

Comment: do you mean ad another Text Widget in Row ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Padding: is the inner space of the element to the edge

Margin: is the space between widgets together

[image]

[image]

Comment: in Text widget wont see the different . so which widget must use to see the difference ?

Comment: As you can see in the picture, we have two containers, one yellow with Padding and the other blue with Margin.

The child inside is yellow has space with the edge which we call it Padding but the blue container has outside space with others which we call it Margin

Answer (score 3):

Easy Method :

**Padding is Space Around means in the container .

Margin  is  Space outside means out side of the container**

Answer (score 2):

Margin is the space around the widget. For example, from the edge of the container to the edge of the phone screen.

Padding is the space within the widget. For example, from the edge of the container to the text in it.

Check out this video from the flutter team around 0:40 to see a quick visual.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html

Comment: Yes I saw the video but I want test it by myself .